# CSS: Deny Attribute Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to add a border to every div that doesn't have the bar class:

HTML

```
<div class="foo bar">010101</div>
<div class="foo">010101</div>
<div class="foo bar">010101</div>
<div class="foo">010101</div>
<div>010101</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background: #ffcc00;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Elements with bar class should not be styled.
I need to use some attribute selector. Are there any attribute selector to do that?

UPDATE:

Fixed using [:not()](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/)
In my case: "div:not(.bar) {"

Thanks.

Comment: @thorn, add that as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
div[class!="bar"] {
   //CSS HERE
}
```

Comment: I couldn't remember that there's a `:not()` - thanks for reminding me! A heads up though - `:not()` didn't exist before CSS3, so there might be some compatibility issues regarding the selector (*cough* IE *cough*).

Comment: There is no such attribute selector in CSS.